# Why can't my .NET 4.5 project use a DLL compiled for .NET 4? (Both use EF 5)

Tags: .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I have an application that consists of a client-side application and a WebApi website.

My client-side stuff is targetting .NET 4 so that I don't have to insist that users install .NET 4.5. My website, however, is entirely under my control, so I'm targetting .NET 4.5.

There is one shared assembly, which I use for data access. It uses Entity Framework 5.

When I build the client application, the DLL used is version 4.4.xxx, whereas when I build the web application, the DLL is 5.0.xxx.

Up until now, I've been able to run the client application with no problems, and I've also been able to run the web application, again without problems.

However, I've now re-created my web application project from scratch (*), and suddenly I can't run it. I get a YSOD saying "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0 ..." at the point where my data-access assembly is first invoked.

Now, it's perfectly clear what that error means - it can't find the v4.4 DLL as used by the data-access assembly - but I don't understand why that's a problem with my new project when it wasn't a problem with my old project. As far as I can see, the same DLLs are referenced in each project.

(*) I should explain why I'm re-creating my project. I originally created the project in VS 2012 RC, and then later upgraded to the release version. Although this supposedly upgraded my project, I've had a few problems with it, and have also noticed some differences v. a newly-created project. So, to be on the safe side - and hopefully circumvent those other problems - I'm re-creating it from scratch.

So, my question: why is this suddenly a problem, and what can I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the code depending on the assemblies set to require the exact version? If so, you will need a [publisher policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06d2bae3.aspx) for the EntityFramework assembly or [bindingRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) for the referencing application (web project).

Comment: Boy am I glad those words are links :-)  The `bindingRedirect` fixed it, thanks. I'd been comparing the project files, not realizing that there was stuff like that in web.config.